# sql/oracle - sum of groupby month/year raising an error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this in oracle

| Date_a | cl_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06.01.2020 | 010 | 10.0 |
| 09.01.2020 | 010 | 12.1 |
| 09.01.2020 | 010 | 5.0 |
| 13.01.2020 | 010 | 8.0 |
| 09.02.2020 | 010 | 13.1 |
| 12.02.2020 | 010 | 0.0 |
| 01.02.2021 | 010 | 14.0 |

i need to find sum of amount in each month/year. The result need to be like this:

| Date_a | cl_id | sum_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06.01.2020 | 010 | 35.1 |
| 09.01.2020 | 010 | 35.1 |
| 09.01.2020 | 010 | 35.1 |
| 13.01.2020 | 010 | 35.1 |
| 09.02.2020 | 010 | 13.1 |
| 12.02.2020 | 010 | 13.1 |
| 01.02.2021 | 010 | 14.0 |

i haave selected only the data for 1 client and wrote code like this, but sql throws an error: npt group by expression

```sql
select Date_a, cl_id , sum(amount)
from table1
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from Date_a), EXTRACT(month from Date_a)
where cl_id  = '010'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all the rows in the output so you want to use an analytic aggregation function rather than using `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT Date_a,
       cl_id,
       sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(date_a, 'MM')) AS sum_a
FROM   table1
where  cl_id = '010';
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (Date_a, cl_id, amount) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-06', '010', 10.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-09', '010', 12.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-09', '010',  5.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-13', '010',  8.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-09', '010', 13.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-12', '010',  0.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', '010', 14.0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE_A | CL_ID | SUM_A |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 06-JAN-20 | 010 | 35.1 |
> | 09-JAN-20 | 010 | 35.1 |
> | 09-JAN-20 | 010 | 35.1 |
> | 13-JAN-20 | 010 | 35.1 |
> | 09-FEB-20 | 010 | 27.1 |
> | 12-FEB-20 | 010 | 27.1 |
> | 01-FEB-20 | 010 | 27.1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5626e269afbab283b17d48211141f97)*

Answer (score 0):

It is analytic form of the `SUM` function you need:

```
SQL> with test (date_a, cl_id, amount) as
  2    (select date '2020-01-06', 10, 10    from dual union all
  3     select date '2020-01-09', 10, 12.1  from dual union all
  4     select date '2020-01-09', 10, 5     from dual union all
  5     select date '2020-01-13', 10, 8     from dual union all
  6     select date '2020-02-09', 10, 13.1  from dual union all
  7     select date '2020-02-12', 10, 0     from dual
  8    )
  9  select date_a, cl_id,
 10    sum(amount) over (partition by to_char(date_a, 'yyyymm')) sum_a
 11  from test  ;

DATE_A          CL_ID      SUM_A
---------- ---------- ----------
06.01.2020         10       35,1
09.01.2020         10       35,1
09.01.2020         10       35,1
13.01.2020         10       35,1
09.02.2020         10       13,1
12.02.2020         10       13,1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```